# how to make a Next.js "Link" 's "href" property optional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've made the Next.js Link as a custom React function with typescript since the "href" property is required for "Link" to be able to call it anywhere I want . so I couldn't used it as a button which working as a submit button in forms

```
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from "next/link";
import { HTMLProps, FC } from "react";

export const LinkButton: FC<LinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>> = ({
  as,
  children,
  href,
  replace,
  scroll,
  shallow,
  passHref,
  className,
  title,
  onClick,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <NextLink
    as={as}
    href={href}
    passHref={passHref}
    replace={replace}
    scroll={scroll}
    shallow={shallow}
  >
    <a className={className} {...rest}>
      {children || title}
    </a>
  </NextLink>
);
```

and when I used it in somewhere it gave me this error

```
<LinkButton onClick={() => alert("hello")} title="Find Events" />

Property 'href' is missing in type '{ onClick: () => void; title: string; }' but required in 
type 'LinkProps'.
```

how could I make href optional then if it doesn't called I can conditionally add a "" tag except of "" tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit `href` property and define as optional:

```
Omit<LinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>, "href"> & { href?: string }
```

and then inside component props destructuring you need to specify default value

```
...
href = "",
...
```

Comment: hi , thank you for your answer but I got an error which I put it on the playground plz check it
https://tsplay.dev/NaY09N

Comment: I don't see link to code sandbox

Comment: I've put it on TSplayground . should I put it on sandbox ?

Comment: I made one https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-cache-bms5v?file=/pages/LinkButton.tsx

Comment: Basically you forgot to put default value to href. See once again my answer (2nd step)